# Problems getting Default Content module to work with Features

Tags: 7, features

I'm trying to export some Default Content when creating a drupal 7 distribution.  Noticed that Phase II is using Default Content module to set default content for OpenPublic.  I can't find any documentation on how to get the module to work.

How do you get the Default Content Module to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.

After you enable the Default Content Module, there will be a new setting for each Node by where you can select Revision information, URL path settings, Comment settings, etc.

This new setting is Machine Name.  You make a machine name for the node of the default content.

Then when you make a new feature (I guess it is best practice to have all of the default content nodes in one feature so when you deactivate the feature all of the default content will turn off and the features will still work) there will be a new component "Content Item".

This will have all of the machine names that you made while creating/editing nodes.

Hopefully someone will find this useful so they don't bang their heads against the wall like I did.